# Retrieving Grails Domain Validation Messages

Tags: java, mysql, spring, grails

I'm pretty new to grails and I'm sure this has been asked multiple times. I have an application which I'm developing in grails. In my service, I make an entry into multiple tables. If one of them fails with a mysql unique constraint exception, I get an error as part of domainInstance.errors object. How do I parse this to return appropriate error code to my controller.

Normally in spring, I was generally adding an exception interceptor for controller to take care of this. Whats the preferred way to do it in grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a validated domain object has validation errors they are stored under `domainObject.errors`, as an implementation of the Spring [Errors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/) interface. To render the errors for a field of this object in a GSP, you typically use something like:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${book}" field="title">
    <div class="errors">
       <g:renderErrors bean="${book}" field="title" as="list" />
    </div>
</g:hasErrors>
```

The exact message that is displayed is resolved from the `message*.properties` files. If you want to get these messages in a controller instead, do this:

```
class MyController {

  MessageSource messageSource
  LocaleResolver localeResolver

    def myAction(Book book) {
        Locale locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(request)

        if (!book.validate()) {
            List allErrorMessages = book.errors.allErrors.collect {
                messageSource.getMessage(it, locale)
            }

            // print all error messages
            println allErrorMessages
        }
    }
}
```